# MariaDB Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats

Tags: mariadb

I'm running MariaDB 10.11 on my CentOS 9 stream server. I've been noticing my memory continue to rise over hours when running `systemctl status mariadb.service` eventually leading to MariaDB crashing.

This has only happened since upgrading my `Laravel` framework earlier this week. However, when checking my MariaDB log file, I'm seeing a ton of the following and wonder whether this is related to the increasing in memory? What are these errors and how do I get rid of them:

```
2024-03-29 12:51:31 5813 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'histogram' at position 10 to have type longblob, found type varbinary(255).
2024-03-29 12:51:31 5813 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'hist_type' at position 9 to have type enum('SINGLE_PREC_HB','DOUBLE_PREC_HB','JSON_HB'), found type enum('SINGLE_PREC_HB','DOUBLE_PREC_HB').
```

Comment: Did you forget to run `mariadb-upgrade` after updating the mariadb packages?

Comment: I've just ran it. What does that command do? Looks like all the phases just say "OK"? Additionally, could not running it account for increased memory usage of mariadb?

Comment: The command should, among other things, make any changes to tables (eg, column_stats) necessitated by the upgrade.  What version were you on?  More precisely, what version of 10.11 are you on now.

Comment: I'm on version `10.11.6-MariaDB`